# What is the format of the request data sent to Server for jqGrid toolbar filters

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the toolbar filter of jqGrid. What is the format of the request data sent to Server for these filters? I checked their documentation for this but I didn't found that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the sent data depends on the value of `stringResult` option of the `filterToolbar` method. You can find the following [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching#calling_convention):

> `stringResult` Determines how to post the data on which we perform
>   searching. When the this option is false the posted data is in
>   key:value pair, if the option is true, the posted data is equal on
>   those as in searchGrid method. See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options).

I personally prefer to use `filterToolbar` with the option `stringResult: true` to have the format of `filters` parameter the same as in case of advance searching (searching with the option `multipleSearch: true`).

Comment: thanks. Actually I gone through the documentation and honestly I am confused then. Now it is clear and I wrote my PHP code already and its working.

Comment: @poddroid: You are welcome! Some parts of jqGrid documentation is really difficult to find.